# convert from one array to double

Tags: java

So I changed my code to double arrays instead one one. But it keeps on telling me that

Houses[] cant convert to House. And I cant seem to find the problem. I want this code to

work as double arrays instead of one array.

```
package ghetto;

import java.math.*;
import ghetto.Houses;
import ghetto.House;
import ghetto.Marker;
import ghetto.HouseType;
import ghetto.Grids;
import ghetto.Ghetto;

public class Houses {
public int size;
public House[][] houses;

public Houses(int size, int blue, int red) {
    if (size == 0)
        return;
    this.houses = new House[size][size];
    House.size = size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            this.houses[i][j] = new House(i, j, HouseType.Vacant);
    }
    // Create Blue
    if (blue != 0) {
        for (int totalBlue = 0; totalBlue < blue;) {
            int choiceRow = (int) (Math.random() * size);
            int choiceCol = (int) (Math.random() * size);
            if (this.houses[choiceRow][choiceCol].who == HouseType.Vacant) {
                this.houses[choiceRow][choiceCol].who = HouseType.Blue;
                System.out.println("Blue house at " + choiceRow + " "
                        + choiceCol);
                totalBlue = totalBlue + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create Red
    if (red != 0) {
        for (int totalRed = 0; totalRed < red;) {
            int choiceRow = (int) (Math.random() * size);
            int choiceCol = (int) (Math.random() * size);
            if (this.houses[choiceRow][choiceCol].who == HouseType.Vacant) {
                this.houses[choiceRow][choiceCol].who = HouseType.Red;
                System.out.println("Red house at " + choiceRow + " "
                        + choiceCol);
                totalRed = totalRed + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

public HouseType getHouseType(int row, int col) {
    System.out.println("house[" + row + "][" + col + "]= "
            + this.houses[row][col].who);
    return this.houses[row][col].who;
    // return HouseType.Red;
}


public void step() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            // Who are my neighbors
            House[][] ns = neighbors(houses[i][j]);

            // How many are red, blue
            int countRed = 0;
            int countBlue = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < 8; n++) {
                if (ns[j][j].who == HouseType.Red) {
                    countRed = countRed + 1;
                }
                if (ns[j][j].who == HouseType.Blue) {
                    countBlue = countBlue + 1;
                }
            }
            // Decide to stay or move
            if (houses[i][j].decide(countRed, countBlue)) {
                houses[i][j].move(ns);
            }
        }
    }
}

public House[][] neighbors(House victim) {
    House[][] n = new House[2][4];

    int row = victim.address / size;
    int col = victim.address % size;

    if (row != 0 && row != (size - 1) && col != 0 && col != (size - 1)) {
        n[0][0] = houses[victim.address - 1];
        n[0][1] = houses[victim.address + 1];
        n[0][2] = houses[victim.address - size];
        n[0][3] = houses[victim.address - size - 1];
        n[0][4] = houses[victim.address - size + 1];
        n[0][5] = houses[victim.address + size];
        n[0][6] = houses[victim.address + size - 1];
        n[0][7] = houses[victim.address + size + 1];
        return n;
    }

    if (row == 0 && col != 0 && col != (size - 1)) {
        n[0] = houses[victim.address - 1];
        n[1] = houses[victim.address + 1];
        n[2] = houses[victim.address + size];
        n[3] = houses[victim.address + size - 1];
        n[4] = houses[victim.address + size + 1];
        n[5] = houses[victim.address + (size * (size - 1))];
        n[6] = houses[victim.address + (size * (size - 1)) + 1];
        n[7] = houses[victim.address + (size * (size - 1)) - 1];
        return n;
    }

    if (row == (size - 1) && col != 0 && col != (size - 1)) {
        n[0] = houses[victim.address - 1];
        n[1] = houses[victim.address + 1];
        n[2] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1))];
        n[3] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1)) + 1];
        n[4] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1)) - 1];
        n[5] = houses[victim.address - size];
        n[6] = houses[victim.address - size - 1];
        n[7] = houses[victim.address - size + 1];
        return n;
    }

    if (col == 0) {
        n[0] = houses[victim.address + (size - 1)];
        n[1] = houses[victim.address + 1];
        n[2] = houses[victim.address - size];
        n[3] = houses[victim.address - size - 1];
        n[4] = houses[victim.address - size + 1];
        n[5] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1))];
        n[6] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1)) + 1];
        n[7] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1)) - 1];
        return n;
    }

    if (col == (size - 1)) {
        n[0] = houses[victim.address - 1];
        n[1] = houses[victim.address + 1];
        n[2] = houses[victim.address - size];
        n[3] = houses[victim.address - size - 1];
        n[4] = houses[victim.address - size + 1];
        n[5] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1))];
        n[6] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1)) + 1];
        n[7] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1)) - 1];
        return n;

    }

    if (col == (size + 1)) {
        n[0] = houses[victim.address - 1];
        n[1] = houses[victim.address + 1];
        n[2] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1))];
        n[3] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1)) + 1];
        n[4] = houses[victim.address - (size * (size - 1)) - 1];
        n[5] = houses[victim.address - size];
        n[6] = houses[victim.address - size - 1];
        n[7] = houses[victim.address - size + 1];

        return n;

}
        return n;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please post the whole method

Comment: Where/How do you declare `houses`?

Comment: Can you shared us the whole class please?

Comment: There's no definition for the HOUSE object type. If it is declared in some other file, make sure you import that file before using it.

Comment: Not sure if i understood what you meant?

Comment: I imported all of the other classes.

Comment: Your error is here:
this.houses = new House[size][size];
you cannot directly assign an object of type House to an object of type Houses. They're both different.

Comment: @Ritikesh But `this.houses` seems to be a `House[][]`.

Comment: Agreed, I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: No I did that and it still gives me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `neighbors(House victim)` method you are trying to assign Houses[] to House object

`n[0][0] = houses[victim.address - 1]` <== in this line n[0][0] represent a House object while  houses[victim.address-1] represent an array. You have to access the `House` object from your `houses[][]` I do not understand your logic but you could try something like this

```
if (row != 0 && row != (size - 1) && col != 0 && col != (size - 1)) {
            n[0][0] = houses[victim.address - 1][victim.j];
            n[0][1] = houses[victim.address + 1][victim.j];
            n[0][2] = houses[victim.address - size][victim.j];
            n[0][3] = houses[victim.address - size - 1][victim.j];
            n[0][4] = houses[victim.address - size + 1][victim.j];
            n[0][5] = houses[victim.address + size][victim.j];
            n[0][6] = houses[victim.address + size - 1][victim.j];
            n[0][7] = houses[victim.address + size + 1][victim.j];
            return n;
        }
```

**Note** : as I mentioned I do not understand your logic so you may have to decide which property of `victim(which is a House Object)` you would like to access the column value for your `houses[row][column]`

Comment: Ok now it is telling me that j is cant be resolved or is not a field?

Comment: make that `public`, that might be `private` in your House class

Comment: or better approach add public getter and setter and access that property

Comment: Ok so now they are double arrays?

Comment: Yeap. Please accept the answer if you are satisfy. Thanks

Comment: I will fix the other and run it and if it work I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on these lines in the neighbors method:

```
    n[0][0] = houses[victim.address - 1];
    n[0][1] = houses[victim.address + 1];
    n[0][2] = houses[victim.address - size];
    n[0][3] = houses[victim.address - size - 1];
    n[0][4] = houses[victim.address - size + 1];
    n[0][5] = houses[victim.address + size];
    n[0][6] = houses[victim.address + size - 1];
    n[0][7] = houses[victim.address + size + 1];
```

(where `houses` and `n` are both declared as `House[][]`).

On the left-hand side of each assignment you have a `House`. On the right-hand side of each you have a `House[]`. You can't assign an array to a scalar. Either you should remove one of the `[]` indices on the left side, or add another on the right to balance it. I can't tell which as I don't know what you're trying to do.

Also, in the `Houses` constructor, the line `House.size = size;` looks dubious. It's assigning to a static field of `House`, while ignoring the instance field of `Houses`. I think you want `this.size = size;` instead.

Comment: But I cant remove one of the [] on the left because then it wont be double arrays right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by double array, but you can't stick an entire array of `House`s in a single `House`, which is what that code is trying to do.

Comment: On the left of each assignment, it's not an array at all, 2D or 1D; it's a single House.