# How to use a method from another class

Tags: java

I want to add this method ( which is located in my Houses class)

```
public void step() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            // Who are my neighbors
            House[][] ns = neighbors(houses[i][j]);

            // How many are red, blue
            int countRed = 0;
            int countBlue = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < 8; n++) {
                if (ns[j][j].who == HouseType.Red) {
                    countRed = countRed + 1;
                }
                if (ns[j][j].who == HouseType.Blue) {
                    countBlue = countBlue + 1;
                }
            }
            // Decide to stay or move
            if (houses[i][j].decide(countRed, countBlue)) {
                houses[i][j].move(ns);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To this class ( ghetto class which is my main class)

```
    startButton = new JButton("start");
    add(startButton);
    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Create a timer
            time = new javax.swing.Timer((int) (1000 * deltaT), this);
            time.start();
            // Add a listener for the timer - which is the step method
            if (e.getSource() == time) 
            {
                Houses h = new Houses();
                h.step();
                //Houses.step();
            }

        }
    });
```

So what I want is that to use the step method (that is located in my Houses class ) in my main class ghetto, here where it is giving the error:

```
           Houses h = new Houses();
           h.step();
```

It says the constructor Houses() is undefined.

Comment: Well...then `the constructor Houses() is undefined` but you're trying to use it.

Comment: You have most likely defined a non-default constructor for `Houses`, but you are trying to use the default (no arg) constructor anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the code you provided in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747035/convert-from-one-array-to-double), the constructor for `Houses` is:

```
public Houses(int size, int blue, int red) { ... }
```

It expects those three arguments, so you have to provide them, which seem to be, the size of the sides of your square house grid, and the initial number of blue and red houses. So maybe:

```
Houses h = new Houses(5, 3, 3);
h.step();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a default constructor for you `Houses` class.

In Houses class :

```
public Houses() {

}
```

You might have one, take a look at your class, you probably autogenerated it with netBeans or Eclipse so it took all class attributes as parameter.

Take a look at OOP principes :

A class House

```
public class House {
    int numberOfPeopleInHouse = 2;
    int numberOfDog = 0;

    public House() {
        //default constructor does nothing but creating a house.
    }
    public House(int dogCount) {
        this.numberOfDog = dogCount;
        /* This particular constructor take a int as parameter, and instead of creating
         * a simple house, we create an house with a modified dog count.
         */
    }
    public void addPeople(int numberOfPeople) {
        this.numberOfPeopleInHouse = this.numberOfPeopleInHouse + numberOfPeople;
    }
}
```

In your main

```
static void main(string[] args) {
    House firstHouse = new House(1);
    //firstHouse contains 2 people and 1 dog

    House secondHouse = new House();
    //secondHouse contains 2 people and 0 dog

    secondHouse.addPeople(2);
    //secondHouse contains 4 people and 0 dog
}
```

Comment: Looking at @Boann answer your constructor expect 3 parameter.

Comment: Don't forget that a constructor is nothing more than a method returning an instance of his own class. If your constructor expect to receive 3 parameters to create a Houses you have to gave him, otherwise, if these 3 parameters are useless you may add a default constructor

Comment: @user3477300 Edited my post, please, don't take wrong habits, stackoverflow is all about community, don't spit on the one helps you,  you never marked your posts as solver when somebody helped you, (to mark as solved you need to click on the cross at the left of an answer).

Comment: Excuse me are you talking to me?? Who said it is working, it is not working. Should I say it is not working? When it works I mark it dont worry. BUT it didnt.

Comment: Boann answered you why you got this error, i do so, if your algorithm have some more logic error, that was not the point of your post.